# nginx location regex, match multiple times

Tags: regex, nginx

How to match multiple times in nginx location regex ?

it seems the {x,x} syntax never works!

for example:

```
location ~ ^/abc/\w{1,3}$ {
  ...
}
```

nerver work!

Comment: try `^/abc/\w\w?\w?$`

Comment: Raj, I know this works, but it seems a little bit ugly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must quote location which contains `{` or `;` characters.

```
location ~ "^/abc/\w{1,3}$" {
    ...
}
```

otherwise nginx parse it as `location ~ ^/abc/\w  { 1, ...` and fails with syntax error.