# How to set max expiry for hashed-filenames?

Tags: angular, nginx, cache-control

How should we setup the nginx-expires setting only for files that include a hash in the name?

e.g. the angular build process will output:

[image]

where:

- `ngs-worker.js` (non-hashed filename) must not be cached
- `polyfills-es5.3eb4a9891f4a514281f1.js` etc. (hashed file-name) can be cached forever

Now, I know I could setup max cache expiry for all `js` files and exclude some (e.g. `ngs-worker.js`)
But this would be disastrous when I forget a non-hashed file or if a future version will produce additional non-hashed files.

How should we handle this?
Maybe use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530010/regular-expression-to-extract-hashes-from-file) to find all hashed-files?

Comment: Construct a regular expression that only matches filenames with a hash, and use a `map` to set the `expires` value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014605/nginx-location-match-regex-not-working/40018271#40018271).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a regex to find all files that include a 20-char hash in the name (surrounded by dots)

```
# e.g. 'polyfills-es5.3eb4a9891f4a514281f1.js'. 'roboto-v18-latin-300.815babffe97b00a1f30b.woff2', ..
location ~* "\.[a-f0-9]{20}\." {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```

note, that the location regex must be quoted - see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765127/1041641)